# Regex to parse C++ enum

Tags: regex, parsing, enums

How can a regular expression be constructed to parse C++ enums?
The enums I tried on looked like

```
enum Temperature
{
    C = 0,
    F=1,     // some elements are commented
    R,       // most elements are not gived a value
    K        // sometimes the last element is succeeded by a comma
} temperature;

// different indent style is used
enum Depth {
    m = 0,
    ft = 1,
} depth;
```

I tried several simple patterns but none is general enough to catch all cases above.

Any regexp wizard who can help me?

Edit: to clarify, I want the name and value, e.g. C and 0.

Comment: Regular expressions cannot "parse" anything. Please, use parsers for parsing!

Comment: A parser would of course be the best solution but may Regex is usable in virtually every programming language and is not dependent on any special platform to run.

Comment: regexps are only for *regular*  languages, and entirely useless for context-free grammars and above. I wonder why people are misusing them so often. There is no point in doing it, no justification whatsoever. Just use the proper parser. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy

Comment: @SK-logic: please elaborate why using regex is not suitable in this particular case.. it makes me mad, if everybody trolls around if they see any combination of {xml, c++, ..} with regex and state nonsense like "regex cannot parse anything". Is the enum definition a context-free grammar??

Comment: @duedl0r, regexps are not suitable because C++ is not a regular language. How would you recognise this enum defintion, to start with? C++ allows constant expressions on the right hand side of `=`, there can be preprocessor macros, etc. So, there is simply *no point*  in using such an unfit tool. In fact, there is very little sense in using regexps anywhere outside of lexers for some very specific languages. They're so much overestimated for some reason.

Comment: @SK-logic: Ok, fair enough. How do you evaluate the constant expression on the right hand side with your parser? You don't, I guess..

Comment: @duedl0r, with C and C++ even a parser is not enough - you can't decide a syntax without having some semantic analysis (knowing what is a type name and what is an identifier, for example). So, yes, for fetching information out of C++ sources you'd need a parser and semantic analysis both implemented. Fortunately, most of the available open source implementations are doing this (Elsa, Clang, ...).

Comment: It really depends on what our requirements are and how we define our problem. If our problem here is "I want to parse enums exactly as a C++ compiler does" yes you shouldn't be using regex, but our problem here is more like "do you see those comma separated statements? the word on the left of = is the name, the one on the right is the value, extract those, and by the way some names may not have a value" this is something that a 5 year old kid can do, using a parser here is like bringing in a C++ expert to do the job, yes you can and it is better but it is waste of a lot of resources.

Comment: @nobody, writing parsers is a way much easier than writing that cryptic regexps things. A PEG grammar for a subset you're talking about is much simpler and much more readable than any possible regexp. Therefore, why using regexps?

Answer (score 3):

That was challenging :) Below is the best I could come up with. Assuming it is given **just the text between { and }** it captures all names and corresponding values:

```
/(\w+)\s*(?:=\s*(\d+)|)\s*,?\s*(?:(?:\n|$)|\/\/.*?(?:\n|$)|)/
```

Answer (score 0):

If we use regex to match enum rather than use it to parse enum. I think it is possible. try with these steps:

step1. make sure the C/C++ source code can be compile successful. 
step2. strip all comments from the C/C++ source code.
step3. match enum

a workable Ruby sample code:

```
# copy from Mastering Regular Expression 3rd
COMMENT = '/\*[^\*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/'
COMMENT2 = '//[^\n]+'
DOUBLE = '"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*"'
SINGLE = '\'(?:\\.|[^\\\'])*\''
# pattern for match enum
ENUM = '\benum\s*(\w+)\s*\{(\s*\w+(?:\s*=\s*\w+)?(?:\s*,\s*\w+(?:\s*=\s*\w+)?)*)\s*(?:,\s*)?\}\s*\w+\s*;'

foo = File.open("foo.cpp", "r").read()
# strip all comments from foo.cpp
foo.gsub!(/(#{DOUBLE}|#{SINGLE})|#{COMMENT}|#{COMMENT2}/, '\1')
bar = []
# match enum...
foo.scan(/#{ENUM}/) do | m |
    printf("%s: %s\n", m[0], m[1].gsub(/\s/, ''))

end
```

output:

```
Temperature: C=0,F=1,R,K
Depth: m=0,ft=1
```