# Using C# Regex to find C++ code patterns (defines & emuns)

Tags: c#, c++, regex

I writing C# program that run over C++ source files and looking for the following things:

```
 #define SOMETHING_A    99
```

and

```
typedef enum {
  EX_A,
  EX_B,
  EX_C,
  EX_D,
  EX_E
} Examples;
```

and

```
enum EXAMPLE2
{
    EX2_A=0,
    EX2_B=1,
    EX2_C=2,
    EX2_D=3,
    EX2_LAST = EX2_D
};
```

My objective is to get the following list of pairs as output:

```
{SOMETHING_A,99}
{EX_A,0}
{EX_B,1}
..
..
{EX2_A,0}
{EX2_B,1}
..
..
```

Can you help me to find the correct regular expressions that match the above 3 patterns?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160304/regex-to-parse-c-enum

Comment: as far as i can see, you want to parse C++ code here. i'd recommend using a parser for that.

Comment: C++ has so many quirks and ways of doing things you'd be better off using a proper C++ parser.

Comment: I'll parse these patterns as soon as I'll find them. They are hiding all over the code, between tons of files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a solution that will work on any c++ files, use a parser instead of regexes.  There are just too many possibilities to account for (different code styles, code that is commented out, etc.).

If you only want to do this on a known set of files, and they have a predictable format and style, a regex is probably ok.  Actually, you are better off using several regexes:

```
/^#define\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)/
```

This only matches define statements that are at the beginning of a line.

Here is the typedef enum:

```
/^\s*typedef\s+enum\s*\{[^\}]+\}[^;]+;/
```

(It's not clear what you want to grab from this one, so I haven't captured anything).

And here is the enum.  This is best done in two steps:

```
/^\s*enum\s+(\S+)\s*\{\s*([^\}]+?)\s*\}\s*;/
```

The first step gets the name of the enum in the first capture group and the content in the second group.  Perform a regex on the second capture group to get the fields and values:

```
/(\S+)\s*=\s*([^\s\,]+)/
```

Each match of this will give you one name/value pair.

These regexes should handle your examples, and they should do a decent job of handling the most common usage in C++ code.  But they are not perfect; if you want a solution that covers all possible constructs, don't use a regex.

*note: you need to make sure the [`match_single_line` flag](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/regex/doc/match_flag_type.html) is off when using these.*

Comment: I tried:    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input,@"^#define\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)", RegexOptions.Singleline);   which results nothing :(

Comment: @ItayB, no, single line has to be **off** :)

Comment: OK, correct, in C# it's RegexOptions.Multiline. It's works for the DEFINE - now I'm checking the emun... I'll comment again shortly

Comment: I tried the first two patterns for the emuns solution.. but can we find one pattern to catch both of them? the enum name is not important to me, later on I'm just parsing the result to get the values of the emuns.... I care only from the content inside the brackets

Comment: @ItayB, I prefer the simplicity of using two regexes.  There is enough complexity in this problem to worry about without trying to combine into a single expression. Still, you could do something like this I suppose: `/^\s*(?:typedef\s+)?enum(?:\s+\w+)?\s*\{\s*([^\}]+?)\s*\}[^;]*;/`